# How can i test mail configuration in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diaspora, exim4

I have setup a diaspora pod on a debian squeeze with exim4 as smtp. If i want to reset my password through user interface (users/password/new) i do not get an email. I can `mail email@domain.tld` via shell.

How can i test my local configuration in production mode?

My configuration looks like this:

```
# from application.yml
mailer_on: true
smtp_address: 'localhost'
smtp_port: '25'
mailer_method: 'smtp'
sendmail_location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
sendmail_exim_fix: true
smtp_authentication: 'none'
smtp_starttls_auto: true
smtp_domain: 'mydomain.tld'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [Mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) useful.